# Engineering Equation Solver - Functions

Tags: function

I must calculate a function on EES.
Function: T(t)=((T_surface-T_infinity)*(e^(-bt)))+T_infinity
t is time and limits are between 1 and 40 second. I need calculate every seconds in 1-40.
How can I write this function in EES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, no differential equation should be solved, no integration, summation or the like should be carried out. Only a calculation with variation of the variable t is to be accomplished.

There are two possibilities. But first: **EES is not 'key-sensitive'**! So you should choose one—`T` or `t`—and the other should get another 'name'. I prefer 'tau' for time.

###### Parametric table

Write the equation in the equation window and aad the parameter you may have(?). Do not define 'tau'. like:

```
T=((T_surface-T_infinity)*(exp(-b*tau)))+T_infinity  
T_surcace = 80[C]  
T_infinity = 20[C]  
b=3
```

Then open the parametic table, add the variables you want to see. At least you should take T and tau. Expand the rows of the table to 40 and enter the respective times. Then press the green *play*-button (top left in the table).

###### Duplicate function:

```
T_surface = 80[C]  
$varinfo tau[] units='s'  
b=0.1[1/s]   
Duplicate i=1,40  
    tau[i] = i*1[s]  
    T[i]=((T_surface-T_infinity)*(exp(-b*tau[i] )))+T_infinity  
End  
T_infinity = 20[C]  
$varinfo T[] units='C'
```